# Date between two dates giving zero counts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract records where `ActionOwnerDate`  is between two specific dates therefore i do:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM T_Warehouse
WHERE CAST(ActionOwnerDate As DATE) BETWEEN CAST('12.01.2020 11:21:08' As Date) AND CAST('12.10.2020 11:21:08' As Date);
```

Nevertheless data is available and should be shown:

[image: Data is available]

What i get is 0 counts. Why is that?

Comment: BETWEEN CAST('20200112 11:21:08' As Date) AND CAST('20201012 11:21:08' As Date)

Comment: As @sergey has suggested use ISO8601 format dates: YYYYMMDD

Comment: Try using a non-ambiguous date format (`yyyymmdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`). Also don;t convert your column to a `date` in the `WHERE`; yes it's SARGable, but that doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: `12.01.2020` could very well be parsed as "December 1 2020" (US date format). Best to always use `yyyy-MM-dd` notation, which is always parsed correctly, and readable to humans as well.

Comment: Why do you specify the time component if you're casting it to a `date`, which doesn't have a time component?

Comment: `CAST(ActionOwnerDate As DATE)` cannot properly use the indexes (not sargeable), use `ActionOwnerDate` directly

Comment: @Charlieface Casting a datetime to date is sargable but it [might not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Here there is no good reason to do any of the casting if the appropriate logic is used.

Comment: @SMor I was aware of  that. More precisely: not fully sargeable, quote "Somewhat surprisingly this is not the same range as your literal values." I've been burnt pretty bad by this before

Answer (score 0):

So the better question is why you choose to do all this casting in the first place. Had you not chosen that path, your code would be working correctly. Was this choice just a kludge to avoid writing proper logic using datetime values? That's my guess.

So don't cast and use lower and upper boundaries that are appropriate for your datatype and goal. For datetime ranges, it is preferred to use an inclusive lower boundary and an exclusive upper boundary (due to the precision of the datatype - no one wants to use a literal time component of 23:59:59.997 ).

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dbo.T_Warehouse as wh
WHERE wh.ActionOwnerDate >= '20200112' 
  AND wh.ActionOwnerDate < '20201013';
```

Notice that I guessed which format you assume in your literals based on your "doesn't work" implication and changed them to be unambiguous. I could have chosen Dec 1 through Dec 10 which is common for US.

Comment: i am just intrested date no time thats why i covert

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert **12.01.2020 11:21:08** as date it converted to **01-Dec-2020**  and  **12.10.2020 11:21:08** converted into **10-Dec-2020** and as you shown your table haven't contain data for between these dates.

If You want to retrieve data between **12-Jan-2020** and **12-Oct-2020** then use below mention query:-
Use **DD-MMM-YYYY** for better understanding.

```
SELECT count(1) FROM T_Warehouse WHERE CAST(ActionOwnerDate As DATE) BETWEEN '12-Jan-2020' AND '12-Oct-2020';
```